# Keyboard Control Not Working As Intended

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm trying to control a single motor.

If I press 'a', then motor 1 should turn to 0, if I press 's', then motor 1 should turn to 180

```
#include <Servo.h>

char key = 0;
const unsigned int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

Servo Servo_0;



void setup()
{

  Servo_0.attach(0);
  Servo_0.write(0);

  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);

 // Serial.println("      Arduino Serial Servo Control");
 // Serial.println("Press < or > to move, spacebar to center");
 // Serial.println();

}

/*
a - 97
s - 115
d - 100
f - 102
*/

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
      key = Serial.read();
      Serial.print("I received: ");
      Serial.println(key, DEC);

     if(key == byte(97))
     {

       Serial.print("Turning Motor 1 to 0 deg");
       Servo_0.write(0);

     }
     else if(key==byte(115))
     {
       Serial.print("Turning Motor 1 to 180 deg");
       Servo_0.write(180);

     }  

     delay(1000);
}
```

But what is happening is that the motors are barely turning after I enter the key onto the Arduino monitor interface. Can anyone diagnose as to what might be happening?

Comment: Why not `if (key == 'a')`?

Comment: Hi, I've changed my code to that statement but it still doesn't turn as intended

Comment: You say motors, but do you mean servos?  If you put in some servo write commands in setup(), worth a 5 second delay after each do they move?

Comment: Does anyone know if I must use "Processing" in order to activate keyboard control??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I see is that your servo is attached to pin 0.

Pins 0 and 1 are used by arduino unos and megas for serial communication, so you can't output to a motor and send/receive serial at the same time. Try moving the servo to pin 3 and see what happens.

In response to your comment, any character sent from any terminal (or other piece of hardware) will work; you do not need to use Processing to communicate with an arduino.